# How to mint offchain NFT in pallet_nfts

Tags: offchain, nft

I want to try out offchain minting feature in [pallet_nfts](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/nfts).
This extrinsic `nfts.mintPreSigned(mintData, signature, signer)` should be used to claim the NFT as a final step. Before that, `mintData` attribute should be signed upfront by the collection owner. How can I do this using polkadot.js UI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to sign the `mintData` object, you would need to get its encoded version first. The easiest way to do this is to open the [mintPreSigned extrinsic's form](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fwestmint-rpc.polkadot.io#/extrinsics) and fill it with the data:

[image: mintPreSigned form]

For the signature, select the `Sr25519` type and put a dummy signature as the value: `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

Now, in the `encoded call data` field you should see smth like this:

0x3425**7b000000c8010000040c6b65791476616c7565000000000000**01aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d

The next step would be to select and copy everything between `0x3425` and `01aaaaaaa....` (it's the encoded `mintData` object) and prefix that with `0x`.
If we take the example above that would be `0x7b000000c8010000040c6b65791476616c7565000000000000`.

Now, you'll need to sign that string.
For that you could use a `subkey sign` command, or a simple JS script similar to this:

```js
import { Keyring } from '@polkadot/api';
import { u8aToHex } from '@polkadot/util';

const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
const pair = keyring.addFromUri('//Alice');
const sig = pair.sign('0x7b000000c8010000040c6b65791476616c7565000000000000');
console.log('sig hex', u8aToHex(sig));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Not so obvious to me, but it works :)
Looking forward to your updates!

Comment: Yeah, that feature really requires a more detailed article :) Pls, let me know if you have more questions or ideas on how to improve the flow.

Answer (score 4):

Offchain minting is a feature built into the NFTs pallet. It is the ability to mint NFTs by having the issuer of a collection sign encoded mint data offchain, this encoded mint data will either designate the account that can mint the NFT or if any account can mint it. Once signed by the issuer, the enduser can mint the NFT onchain via the `mint_pre_signed` extrinsic.

Okay.. so how do we do this in Substrate?

Follow these steps.

First we have to create an NFT collection.

[image]
[image]

Encoded call data:

```
0x2a0000d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d0000000000000000010a000000000000000000000000000000
```

Next we have to do three things:

- create our mint data (this will be the NFT we want to be minted)
- encode the mint data
- sign the encoded mint data

  - the account that signs the encoded mint data should be an issuer for the collection, meaning, they have approval to mint

> Note: when creating the mint data, if you only intend one account to have permission to mint that NFT then specify this in the `only_account` attribute otherwise, any account will be able to mint the NFT.

We can use PolkadotJs Apps to construct the mint data like so:

[image]
[image]

> We are not going to submit this transaction. We are only using it to obtain the encoded mint data. You could also construct this using JavaScript and PolkadotJS API or similar.

Keep in mind that `onlyAccount` here is set to `None`. This means that any account that has access to this mint data, once it is signed, could mint this NFT.

For `deadline` specify the block number where this transaction will be valid for. The transaction will be valid up to this block number.

Notice the encoding details on the bottom right of the screen.

From that we can concatenate and construct our encoded mint data:

```
0x000000000000000004106e616d65304272756e6f2047616c76616f0000d0070000
```

We now have to sign the encoded mint data.

[image]

Alternatively, here is a nice script:

```js
import { Keyring } from '@polkadot/keyring';
import { u8aToHex } from '@polkadot/util';
import { cryptoWaitReady } from '@polkadot/util-crypto';

export const sign = async () => {
    await cryptoWaitReady();

    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
    const pair = keyring.addFromUri('//Alice');
    const sig = pair.sign('0x000000000000000004106e616d65304272756e6f2047616c76616f0000d0070000');
    console.log('Signature: ', u8aToHex(sig));
}
```

Output:

```
Signature:  0x163b1eb3420cf2b78b4ffedca11e9618dd8528e6e7485cb343379d9db6aa84305f9995b6bf2120d4541d36a9056f6a158ccc5e8745794657073ae23cb3de838f
```

We can now create the `mintPreSigned` extrinsic and include our signature:

[image]
[image]

Click "Submit Transaction" and you have now minted a crisp, fresh NFT.

[image]

Success! Done.

### Resources

Offchain Minting PR

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13158

Test for offchain minting (super useful to read):

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0cf64f8bd72d719818be2f109c0919c7c9325cd1/frame/nfts/src/tests.rs#L3171-L3337

Comment: Very informative video and well written post, thanks @Bruno